# Top shows a lot of php processes sleeping

Tags: php, bash, process

We have a utility server for running scheduled php cronjobs,and after a while when I check top, it shows around 100~ sleeping php processes like this:

```
 6310 user  20   0  223m  16m 9748 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.04 /usr/local/bin/php72-cgi -d open_basedir="/home/user/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear"
```

As the process list doesn't show the parent script or the actual script name it's hard for me to diagnose which script is generating so many sleeping processes. As you can see, the memory usage is minimal, but I still feel like this shouldn't happen. What's the easiest way to find out the culprit script and should I even worry about sleeping processes?

Comment: maybe could be useful `pstree -p 6310`, `lsof -p 6310` and to see special files in `/proc/6310` like `less /proc/6310/cmdline`

Comment: nope, gives the same result :/ 
`
/usr/local/bin/php72-cgi^@-d^@open_basedir="/home/user/:/tmp:/usr/share/pear"^@
`

Answer (score 0):

To understand why, you should list the process with its parent, thanks to this command (adapt the pid to your current execution):

```
pstree -H 6310 -ps
```